# Difference between formal tensor series and vector space of polynomial?

Tags: stochastic-processes, tensor-products, tensors, hopf-algebras, stochastic-pde

The question is related to the link https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123619302460#br0110 where in page 12 they define the vector space of formal tensor series over $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ by

$T((\mathbb{R^{1+d}}))=\prod_{k=0}^\infty$$(\mathbb{R}^{d+1})^{\otimes k}$

and in the very next line the vector space of polynomials is defined over $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ by

$T(\mathbb{R^{1+d}})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty$$(\mathbb{R}^{d+1})^{\otimes k}$

Can anyone please describe me a bit what is difference between this expression? I can see one uses product and other is summation but with that alone I do not understand the significance/difference. As I understand any series is a summation but then how formal tensor series is defined as a product?

I would love to hear any comments.

Comment: Generally, the difference between an infinite direct sum and an infinite direct product is that in the sum only finitely many terms can be nonzero, with no such restriction on the product. This mirrors the distinction between polynomials and power series, where a polynomial can be thought of as a power series with only finitely many nonzero coefficients.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for your comment, do you also mean there is no difference in calculating/evaluating the infinite direct sum and infinite direct product?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *calculating*. I think of direct sums and products as sets, and the direct sum is a subset of the direct product. The direct product of infinitely many copies of the reals, say, is the set of all infinite sequences of reals; the direct sum would be the set of all sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, calculating/evaluating was not appropriate, I was trying to understand the difference in the elements of each set, which leads to those words.  It seems the direct product was introduced to increase the size of the direct sum space. I am trying to understand how this is helping in renormalization?

Comment: Maybe it could be useful to you to check a simpler example. Take $d=0$ and see what you find. Formal tensor series will turn out to be formal power series over $\mathbb{R}$ and polynomials will turn out to be ordinary polynomials. Then come back to the general case of $d >0$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about renormalization, and can't help you with that.